# Trying to simulate a C union with Swift gives a runtime exception

Tags: swift

In C:

```
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned short u16;

typedef union {
  struct { u8 l,h; } b;
  u16 w;
} Register;
```

In Swift (using enumeration with associated values):

```
enum Register {
    case b(UInt8, UInt8)
    case w(UInt16)

    var l: UInt8 {
        switch(self) {
        case .b(let l, _): return l
        case .w(let w): return UInt8(w)
        }
    }

    var h: UInt8 {
        switch(self) {
        case .b(_, let h): return h
        case .w(let w): return UInt8(w >> 8)
        }
    }

    var w: UInt16 {
        switch(self) {
        case .b(let l, let h): return UInt16(l | (h << 8))
        case .w(let w): return w
        }
    }
}
```

This works:

```
let regA = Register.b(255, 0)
print(regA.l)
print(regA.h)
let regB = Register.w(UInt16(256))
print(regB.w)
```

And this doesn't, causing a runtime exception:

```
print(regA.w)
print(regB.l)
print(regB.h)
```

I can't figure out the problem as it seems very impossible to track the issue inside enum definition.

Comment: I would not define an enum for that purpose. Why should it make a difference if the value was created from two bytes or from one word? I would define either a struct, or an `extension UInt16` with computed properties `lowByte`, `highByte`, similar as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/28010707/1187415.

Comment: I accepted the answer from @vacawama because it fixed my problem at bay but I will certainly adopt your solution when I refactor my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues.

For issue 1, you are creating a `UInt8` from a `UInt16` which will overflow if you don't limit the value.  You can either use `UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: w)` or `UInt8(w & 0xff)`.

For issue 2, `l` and `h` in the statement `UInt16(l | (h << 8))` are `UInt8` values, so you are overflowing `UInt8` and you need to convert to `UInt16` **before** shifting and or-ing.

Your code now works with those 2 modifications:

```
enum Register {
    case b(UInt8, UInt8)
    case w(UInt16)

    var l: UInt8 {
        switch(self) {
        case .b(let l, _): return l
        case .w(let w): return UInt8(w & 0xff)  // issue 1
        }
    }

    var h: UInt8 {
        switch(self) {
        case .b(_, let h): return h
        case .w(let w): return UInt8(w >> 8)
        }
    }

    var w: UInt16 {
        switch(self) {
        case .b(let l, let h): return UInt16(l) | UInt16(h) << 8  // issue 2
        case .w(let w): return w
        }
    }
}
```