# How to divide UInt8 into 3 bits and 5 bits

Tags: ios, swift, bit

I am wondering how to input UInt8 divided into 3bit and 5bit.

```
Var val: UInt8 = 0

Val.bit3 = 0x06 // 110 
Val.bit5 = 0x11 // 10000
```

i want result:
11010000 or 10000110 (3bit / 5bit or 5bit / 3bit)

```
extension UInt8 {
    var bit3 : UInt8 {
        get {
            ??
        }
        set(newValue) {
            ??
        }
    }

    var bit5 : UInt8 {
        get {
            ??
        }
        set(newValue) {
            ??
        }
    }
}
```

How do I do bitwise operations to get the result above?

... Thank you

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/a/28010707/1187415 should be easily adaptable to your needs.

Comment: Also, Swift is not Visual Basic or something: `var` != `Var` and `Val` != `val`. And `0x11` = `0b10001`.

Comment: I urge you to make better names for these properties :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that

```
extension UInt8 {
    var bit3 : UInt8 {
        get {
            return (self & 0b1110_0000) >> 5
        }
        set(newValue) {
            self &= 0b0001_1111
            self |= ((newValue << 5) & 0b1110_0000)
        }
    }

    var bit5 : UInt8 {
        get {
            return self & 0b0001_1111
        }
        set(newValue) {
            self &= 0b1110_0000
            self |= (newValue & 0b0001_1111)
        }
    }
}
```

`bit3` here is "top" and `bit5` is "bottom".

EDIT: Forgot to clean bits before setting

Comment: With your code, when `set`, the result is bitwise-ORed to the original value. I guess replacing the original value would be the desired behaviour.

Comment: @OOPer, yeah, fixed it.

Comment: @OOPer, What should I do?